# Pracma::Lcm() only returns NA in loop

Tags: r, lcm

I am trying to obtain the least common multiplier of the prime numbers in between 1 and 20:

```
x <- expand.grid(c(2,3,7,11,13,17,19),c(2,3,7,11,13,17,19))
l <- c()
# loop
for(i in length(x[,1])){
l[i] <- pracma::Lcm(x[i, 1], x[i, 2])
}
# gives
tail(l)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA 19
```

Interestingly, the loop returns only NA's besides the first and last value, this doesn't make sense since one can obtain the values by hand:

```
pracma::Lcm(x[4, 1], x[4, 2])
[1] 22
```

Can anyone spot what I am missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can initiate `l` with instead of `c()`.  Also, `length` is a single value.  We need `seq_len(nrow(x))`

```
l <- numeric(nrow(x))

for(i in seq_len(nrow(x))) {
     l[i] <- pracma::Lcm(x[i, 1], x[i, 2])
 }

l
#[1]   2   6  14  22  26  34  38   6   3  21  33  39  51  57  14  21   7  77  91 119 133  22  33  77  11 143 187 209  26  39  91 143  13
#[34] 221 247  34  51 119 187 221  17 323  38  57 133 209 247 323  19
```

---

If we initiate as `c()`, then inside the loop, it would be

```
 l <- c(l, pracma::Lcm(x[i, 1], x[i, 2]))
```

---

Also, the `pracma::Lcm` is vectorized, so no need to loop over each rows

```
pracma::Lcm(x[,1], x[,2])
#[1]   2   6  14  22  26  34  38   6   3  21  33  39  51  57  14  21   7  77  91 119 133  22  33  77  11 143 187 209  26  39  91 143  13
#[34] 221 247  34  51 119 187 221  17 323  38  57 133 209 247 323  19
```

---

In the OP's code, the

```
length(x[,1])
#[1] 49
```

is a single number i.e. the last row, here, i.e. only looping through that last row

Second issue is during the assignment, where we assign with a `length` of 0 and when we use index, it is creating a `NULL`

```
l <- c()
length(l)
#[1] 0
l[1]
#NULL
```

Comment: Can u elaborate on why you think that would solve my problem ?

Comment: @BeginneR. There are two issues in the code, can you check `length(x[,1])` it is a single number.  So, looping means it is only looping at the last row, 2) You initiated `l <- c()` Now, check `l[1]`